EfCore+MySQL how to query DateTime that has been converted with ToBinary
The DbContext has been configured to convert DateTime objects as such:
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder) {
   configurationBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
     .HaveConversion<long>();
}

which from what I understand uses DateTimeToBinaryConverter, which in turn uses DateTime.ToBinary().
As expected, the database contains a bunch of negative BIGINT numbers where dates would otherwise exist.
My question is basically how to convert these BIGINT values back into a datetime format that I can work with -- so that, e.g., I can use date_add.
I am using MySQL. from_unixtime does not work, since these values are not unix timestamps.
Any pointing to the right direction appreciated! Thanks.

Why do you convert the DateTime value to a long value?

Why don't use datetime.frombinary to convert the date back?

@Progman from what I understand, C# DateTime does not map to MySQL datetime directly, and I need a conversion.
@Shadow I need to run queries in the database server, and not in the front-end. For example, "select * from Payments where Timestamp > some_date_selection_in_the_UI".
If I write this in LINQ with FromBinary, it doesn't compile because my model assumes .NET DateTime -- but the compiled SQL doesn't work in the server.

@dow EF has native support for DateTime, they can be saved in an appropriate table column without problem (like DATETIME in MySQL or DATETIME2(7) for SQL Server). You don't need to convert anything.

@Progman you are right, with one caveat.. Oracle's MySQL driver doesn't perform the .NET DateTime to MySQL datetime(6) conversion, so I needed something else. However, it turns out that Pomelo does it just how you describe.
